How can I sign in with Google post email?
I am using supabase sign in with google for my web app auth. I would like to send an email to users that it is their first login (they don't have a user in supabase yet).
What is the suggested approach I should look into?

I ended up using my mail sas via API
https://github.com/getbrevo/brevo-node
